# PHPWord how to replace HTML Tags

Tags: php, html, phpword

I am creating a word doc using PHPWord. The content of the doc is dynamic and the content may contain HTML Tag like following:

```
<strong>Problem statement</strong>

<p>The text may be<em>bold</em> subject to very peculiar conditions</p>

<ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
</ul>
```

The doc is creating but the in the doc the content is showing the html tags.

How to replace these tags with proper word document tags so that the word doc shows exactly same as HTML view with proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to make a function like this:

```
function convertTags($text){
        $text= str_replace("<strong>", "<w:b val="true"/>", $text);
        $text= str_replace("</string>", "<w:b val="false"/>", $text);
        // and all the tags like that. You may use an array and loop through it.
       return $text;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer demonstrates, quite nicely, why using `str_replace` and regex's are a bad idea when used to consume/parse or otherwise manipulate markup: typo's will get you, malformed markup will too, not to mention whitespace and tag-soup. Just parse the HTML

Comment: I tried this on but in the corrosponding doc file it is showing in followin manner:  <w:b>Background with problem statement</w:b>

Comment: @MohammadAbdullahJunayeed: Have you read the note at the bottom of my answer? It seems NurAzije used the same tags as I did (which are the ones used by **open** office, not sure what MS Office uses, so they might not work. I'd also, once again, strongly recommend you look for ways to have word render the HTML as-is, like it does when you copy-paste a piece of a website, that'd probably be the easiest sollution

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace` to replace the html-tags with the word-tags. Example:

```
$str = "<b>Hello World</b>";
$str = str_replace("<b>", "<strong>", $str);
$str = str_replace("</b>", "</strong>", $str);
//Gives "<strong>Hello World</strong>"
```

Read more [here](http://php.net/str_replace)

Comment: There still are too many things a simple `str_replace` can't deal with: upper-case tags (things like `<B>` are simple, but `<Div>` or `<DiV>`...), attributes, whitespace (`< / B >`). you'll soon end up with a huuuuge array for each tag `str_replace(['<b>', '<  b>', < / b>', ...], '<strong>', $html);`, and you'll have to call `str_replace` for _each tag_. You if you find yourself putting together tons of silly arrays (and regexes), you should know that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Sure, you might think using regex's to counter the case and white space problems, but that way [madness lies](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1230836). Don't. Do. It. the only _right way TM_ to process markup is by means of a parser